# File questions (How to prevent an error when the user enters the wrong file name)

Tags: python, file

Regarding the kind of program that I am trying to create, I am trying to create a program that takes an input of a text file name in order for the program to check if the file exists or not in Jupyter notebook. If the user types the existing file in the input box, then the program reads the file successfully. However, if the user enters the file name that doesn’t exist, then the program generates an error. I am actually trying to prevent my program from generating an error. Instead, my question is how can I create a program to display a message “Sorry, the name of a file that you just entered doesn’t exist” when the user enters the file name that doesn't exist? Could someone please show me how to do that? (I screenshot my program and pasted the link down below.)

https://ibb.co/C965jLr

Best Regards

Comment: Please show us your code and the error, not a link to images on the web

Answer (score 1):

You need to use try and except in this way:

```
file_name = input("Enter file name")
try:
    with open(file_name + '.txt', mode='r') as f:
        message = f.read()
        print('This file exists')
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("Sorry this file doesn't exist")
```